# Posting comment asking what the end result of code is and learn from the question?

Tags: discussion

Whenever I have some time, I try to go through the questions to see if there's something I can contribute to. Very often, I see questions with some really interesting code that I know I could use *if* I knew what the end result is.

For example, if I see a question asking how to synchronize threads, I can surmise that the poster's trying to run several tasks in parallel, and I know that I can use the answers later on in a project. But there are questions where I see the code and try to imagine why the poster would use it, and I come up blank. I know that if the poster explains more or less what he's trying to accomplish, I can use it later on.

Is it OK to ask in the question what the end result of the posted code is or maybe why he's using that code?

Comment: If you are referring to questions, they *should* have the desired result stated to get the best possible answer.

Comment: @codeMagic, I didn't know that. Can I post an example of a question here so you have an idea of what I mean?

Comment: You can add a link to an example question for reference if you think it will help.

Comment: This one here, even if it was marked as duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25810773/convert-string-to-an-interface-parameter

Answer (score 4):

You're more than welcome to ask for greater context of the problem that a question is asking about.  It's not *wrong* to ask.

Of course, the question author isn't obligated to answer such a question.

Some questions may be unanswerable without additional context, some may simply have lower quality answers than they would otherwise have, and some questions really don't need such context at all.